# Why did Legolas switch languages?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

In the [second Hobbit movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1170358/?ref_=nv_sr_1) when Tauriel is after the dwarfs, and Legolas catches up with her, he starts speaking in Elvish, then switches to English and then back to Elvish.

Why would he do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess the most obvious answer is that they wanted to show off the Elven language in the movie.

However, there are other real life examples. In general, people that speak in a non native language (say they are working in an English speaking country, but weren't born in one) tend to fall back to their mother language when they are agitated. So it does make sense for Legolas to fall back to the Elvish language when he is stating something he is very agitated about. That makes sense. What doesn't make sense is, that he is speaking to Tauriel in English at all. He has no reasons to resort to the human language to speak to her. So it's obviously about showing off the Elven language in the movie. Or rather not having to put subtitles under all the dialogs.

Comment: +1 on the explanation. As a person living in a country that doesnt speak my native toungue I can say that when I speak in "native" with friends/Family I sometimes switch to a language of the country we all reside in... It is a common phenomenon and it happens often. Sometimes it is agitation/excitement related, sometimes I just cant remember the darn phrase in my "native" and have to use a substitute. This might be the case in the movie also. OR It could be that they just didnt have time to invent enough words or Orlando just couldn't say them in a beliveable fashion without the E

Comment: @Cherubel: "because they didn't have time to invent enough words" ... unlikely, considering this is Elvish which has a fat dictionary. But your other points stand.

Answer (score 4):

As a Silvan elf (according to the movie), Tauriel likely speaks a different dialect of Elvish to that spoken by Legolas, who is Sindarin (it's established in many places that the Silvan dialects were different).  There may be some elements of mutual intelligibility but they also likely need to speak Westron (represented by English) a lot of the time too.

Going by this theory, Tauriel would have ancestry in the second clan (Tatyar), half of whom became the Noldor and the other half of whom remained Avari; this clan were known to occasionally have red hair (e.g. Feanor's wife and some of his sons) so the theory fits.

Comment: Really? After thousands of years of dwelling with the Silvans in Mirkwood? I suppose Westron hadn't even evolved to a Hobbit-understandable form back then.